# How do I render faces properly in 3d?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to render the faces of a cube properly in 3d. This is my code:

```py
import pygame, sys, math

def rotate2d(pos,rad): x,y=pos; s,c=math.sin(rad),math.cos(rad); return x*c-y*s,y*c*+x*s

class Cam:
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0), rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def events(self,event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            x,y = event.rel
            x/=200; y/=200
            self.rot[0]+=y; self.rot[1]+=x

    def update(self,dt,key):
        s = dt*10
        if key[pygame.K_q]: self.pos[1]+=s
        if key[pygame.K_e]: self.pos[1]-=s
        x,y = s*math.sin(self.rot[1]), s*math.cos(self.rot[1])
        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[0]+=x;self.pos[2]+=y
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[0]-=x;self.pos[2]-=y
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0]-=y;self.pos[2]+=x
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0]+=y;self.pos[2]+=x

class Cube:
    verticies = (-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
    faces = (0,1,2,3),(4,5,6,7),(0,1,5,4),(2,3,7,6),(0,3,7,4),(1,2,6,5)
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0)):
        x,y,z = pos
        self.verts = [(x+X/2,y+Y/2,z+Z/2) for X,Y,Z in self.verticies]


pygame.init()
w,h = 400,400; cx,cy = w//2,h//2
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cam = Cam((0,0,-5))

pygame.event.get; pygame.mouse.get_rel()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0); pygame.event.set_grab(1)

cubes = [Cube((0,0,0)),Cube((-2,0,0)),Cube((2,0,0))]

while True:
    dt = clock.tick()/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
        cam.events(event)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for obj in cubes:
        vert_list = []; screen_coords = []
        for x,y,z in obj.verts:
            x-=cam.pos[0]; y-=cam.pos[1]; z-=cam.pos[2]
            x,z = rotate2d((x,z), cam.rot[1])
            y,z = rotate2d((y,z), cam.rot[0])
            vert_list += [(x,y,z)]
            if z == 0: z = 0.001
            f=200/z
            x,y = x*f, y*f
            screen_coords+=[(cx+int(x), cy+int(y))]

        face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []
        for f in range(len(obj.faces)):
            face = obj.faces[f]
            on_screen = False
            for i in face:
                x,y = screen_coords[i]
                if vert_list[i][2]>0 and x>0 and x<w and y>0 and y<h: on_screen = True; break

            if on_screen:
                coords = [screen_coords[i] for i in face]
                face_list +=[coords]
                face_color += (128,128,128)
                depth += [sum(sum(vert_list[j][i] for j in face)**2 for i in range(3))]
        order = sorted(range(len(face_list)),key=lambda i: depth[i], reverse=0)
        for i in order:
            try:
                pygame.draw.polygon(screen, face_color[i], face_list[i])
            except: pass
    pygame.display.flip()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cam.update(dt,key)
```

This renders to the screen, but not properly. What am I doing wrong? There should be three cubes, visible to the user, and the user should be able to move around them freely. Instead, the program renders the faces improperly at the wrong coordinates. Maybe this is something to do with the `rotate2d()` function? Though this seems to be working properly. I think I am processing the vertexes properly too. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is a typo in `rotate2d`. It has to be `x*c-y*s,y*c+x*s` rather than `x*c-y*s,y*c*+x*s` (focus on `*+`). Further more `pygame.event.get()` rather than `pygame.event.get` (before the application loop)

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the comment Rabbid76 made, the only thing out of whack is that you put the `face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []` line *inside* the for loop. Instead of this:

```
for obj in cubes:
    […]
    face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []
    […]
```

your for loop should look like this:

```
face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []
for obj in cubes:
    […]
    […]
```

Also, here are some code suggestions made by Rabbid76 to improve various things about this exact code:

- [Depth issue with 3D graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690079/depth-issue-with-3d-graphics)
- [Close range 3d display messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330496/close-range-3d-display-messed-up)